# Can I add a second SSD with Windows10 to my laptop that already has an SSD with Windows10?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

The laptop has an SSD with Windows 10 and a second slot for an SSD and I want a second SSD with windows 10 were I can do my own things. Is there a problem having two SSDs with Windows10 and is anything I should know about this? Also what software should I use for dual boot is there is any required?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your earlier question. [Can I add a second SSD with Windows 10 to a laptop that already has an SSD with Windos10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1638894/can-i-add-a-second-ssd-with-windows-10-to-a-laptop-that-already-has-an-ssd-with)

Comment: Not at all. :)) I know that I am allowed to add one and I know that the laptop already has two SSD slots! I need to know how should I do it and what to use for using this config safely

Comment: It is simply missing the essential detail that this is a corporate machine & not yours to play with. Even if not this is a) too broad & b) asking for software recommendations.

Comment: Is missing because is not an important detail. Is my company and I just want to separate the two activities by separating the OSes and SSDs

Comment: Rather than posting an identical question you should have edited your original question to clarify and explain the actual problem you are having. Telling us what you have tried and where you are stuck can help us to help you.